# Why do my iptable rules keep growing longer and longer

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I added port 80 and port 3306 to my iptables rules on a VM.Standard.E2.1.Micro running Ubuntu on Oracle by doing:

`sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`

`sudo netfilter-persistent save`

`sudo netfilter-persistent reload`

and

`sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT`

`sudo netfilter-persistent save`

`sudo netfilter-persistent reload`

When I check my iptables rules using `sudo iptables -nL -v` or any other command, I can see that the rules seem to be multiplying.

Am I doing something wrong here when it comes to adding rules and saving rules?

My current rules look like this, and they weren't this long before I add those two rules. Can you please help?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text you could just copy&paste.

Comment: Somehow your iptables get copied and pasted into again without clearing the former settings. Probably a third program, like a software firewall or some NAT ruling or some DHCP is messing arround your iptables with a wrong implemented config. Or maybe your OS has an out-of-the-box iptables restore mechanic which I don't know.